# Using gsub() in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a big data table (about 20,000 rows). One of its columns contains in integers from 1 to 6.

I also have a character vector of car models (6 models).

I'm trying to replace integers with corresponding car model.(just 2 in this example)

```
 gsub("1",paste0(labels[1]),Models)
 gsub("2",paste0(labels[2]),Models) 
 ...
```

"Models" is the name of a column.

```
labels <- c("Altima","Maxima")
```

After fighting with it for 12+ hours gsub() isn't working(

sample data:
                  mydata<-data.table(replicate(1,sample(1:6,10000,rep=TRUE)))
                  labels<-c("altima","maxima","sentra","is","gs","ls")

Comment: Can you show some of your data?  There is almost certainly a better way, e.g. `match` `which` or `merge`.

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure how to show my data here. but here is better explanation, i hope. models is a data table, consisting of a single column and 20000 rows. labels is a character vector with 6 names total. Values in the Models data table are integers 1 through 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `gsub` here. What you are describing is a factor variable.

If you data is

```
mydata <- data.table(replicate(1,sample(1:6,1000,rep=TRUE)))
models <- c("altima","maxima","sentra","is","gs","ls")
```

you could just do

```
mydata[[1]] <- factor(mydata[[1]], levels=seq_along(models), labels=models)
```

If you really wanted a character rather than a factor, then

```
mydata[[1]] <- models[ mydata[[1]] ]
```

would also do the trick. Both of these require the numbers are continuous and start at 1.

Comment: Well, it works on my test data. If your data is different somehow, perhaps you could post some sample data in the original question. Otherwise, i'm not sure how to respond to your comment.

Comment: mydata<-data.table(replicate(1,sample(1:6,10000,rep=TRUE)));    
models<-c("altima","maxima","sentra","is","gs","ls")

Comment: @AlexKors I've updated with the data.table syntax, but it's really just the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using factor() in the following way - worked for me on your test data.  Assuming that name of the first column in mydata is V1 (the default)

```
mydata$V1 <- factor(mydata$V1, labels=models)
```